# Can a TrueCrypt volume be ejected (or the app quit) upon entering sleep?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, truecrypt

Is it possible to force all TrueCrypt mounted volumes to eject when my Mac goes to sleep or to have TrueCrypt quit (causing them to unmount)? I'm looking for a little extra "easy" security when I move my Mac around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [TrueCrypt docs](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/command-line-usage), the dismount option could be added to your shutdown script.

```
truecrypt /d
```

or

```
truecrypt -d
```

Comment: Can someone link this to or provide details how to execute a shutdown script at sleep time to complete this answer?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I found a few apps that'll help me do this since there is no sleep/wake script.

Comment: @Matt, Care to share what apps you found?

Comment: @Nate sorry, but i never really solved for it.